# Is there any way to do this effect in React Native?

Tags: instagram, effect

im just wondering if is there any way to do this effect in react native as well?

On android when you scroll on the direct message screen up and down, you will notice that background of the chat bubbles are changing.

[Instagram Direct Message](https://css-tricks.com/recreating-the-facebook-messenger-gradient-effect-with-css/)